# QGIS overview map of atlas - setting a color

Tags: qgis, polygon, color, atlas, map-overviews

I have an overview map of atlas in atlas print layout. How can i set an automatic change of color for atlas map in overview map?
E.G. I have 600 atlas maps. In oveview map every atlas map is a polygon with a black line and and no filling. I want for every atlas map change color of line of that 1 different polygon (atlas extent) in overview map.
[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Go to Item Properties - Overviews and set a Frame Style showing only a border:

[image]

Comment: Thank you! Yes, that was my problem. Also is it possible to set a color of number of that zoom extent? So both border and number of zoom extent will have the same color?

Comment: Nice, please accept my answer with the checkbox. Do you mean the label? I dont know

Comment: yes, I mean label.

Comment: I redirected my question to https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/397631/setting-a-label-color-of-zoom-extent.